# Get requested URL for a custom 404 page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

So the problem that I am having is I am trying to get the requested URL after that displays a 404 and do some Apex logic on it to route them to the correct place.

Now from reading the documentation I figured I could do something like this.

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();
```

The problem is that returns the URL of the current 404 Visualforce page.

As an example the user requests:

https://site.force.com/something/path/id/72 which is not a valid path and gets redirected to my custom 404 page. The URL on the top of the browser is still https://site.force.com/something/path/id/72.

Yet when my controller calls `ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl()`, the page I get back from this is  /apex/Custom404Page.

How can the controller get https://site.force.com/something/path/id/72?

Also in Visualforce I notice I can call `{!$Site.OriginalUrl}` to get back /something/path/id/72. Which is what I want. Can I access this global variable anyway in the controller? Is there a easy way without using JS to have the controller get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that last part helped me find the solution. I can get `{!$Site.OriginalUrl}` from Apex.

So I can just call `Site.getOriginalUrl();` which returns back the right URL. As the method's documentation says it does the following.

`getOriginalUrl()` - Returns the original URL for this page if it’s a
   designated error page for the site; otherwise, returns null.